# Экранирование строки при работе с sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, экранирование

Всем добрый день. Сломал голову с экранированием строки. СУБД MSSQL. В хранимой процедуре использую конструкцию

```
 exec sp_executesql 'select *
 into Extdb.tmp.bulgurov_february2018_potok_status_2
 from openquery([HANA],''Select * from'+ @SYSTEM+'.february2018_status_2'')';
```

но получаю стандартную ошибку 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
'

При этом засунув этот же кусок в SELECT получаю вполне валидную строку запроса
Запрос:

```
 declare  @SYSTEM varchar (100)
 set @SYSTEM = ' t2_kbulgurov'
 select 'select *
 into Extdb.tmp.bulgurov_february2018_potok_status_2
 from openquery([HANA],''Select * from '+ @SYSTEM+'.february2018_status_2'')'
```

Результат:

```
select *  
into Extdb.tmp.bulgurov_february2018_potok_status_2  
from openquery
     ([HANA],'Select * from  t2_kbulgurov.february2018_status_2')
```

Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя использовать выражение в качестве параметра процедуры, это должна быть или константа, или переменная типа nvarchar.

[Это явно указано в описании процедуры sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments)

Так должно работать:

```
DECLARE  @SYSTEM nvarchar(100);

SET @SYSTEM = 't2_kbulgurov';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SELECT @SQL = N'select *
 into Extdb.tmp.bulgurov_february2018_potok_status_2
 from openquery([HANA],''Select * from ' + @SYSTEM +'.february2018_status_2'')';

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Невнимательность погубит меня, спасибо, в таком формате всё действительно работает!